# Override function and skip part of the original funtion

Tags: php

My problem is as follows. I want to create an override for an existing Method and disable or skip a part of code from the original one from being executed.

Inside the Class which extends the abstract Class, i have added the same Method. I can't create a new Method to solve my problem, because the Method is different on multiple versions of this specific CMS system.

The part I want to disable or skip by creating an override, is the same in all of those different versions though.

I already went through the PHP manual and found the PECL apd function override_function.

PECL can't be used though, because not everybody who will be using the plugin i'm trying to create, has the PECL extention installed for PHP.

This is what i have so far:

```
public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown',
        $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false,
        $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
    {

//This is the part that has to be disabled
if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email)) {
                            Mail::Send(
                                (int)$order->id_lang,
                                'order_conf',
                                Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
                                $data,
                                $this->context->customer->email,
                                $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
                                null,
                                null,
                                $file_attachement,
                                null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
                            );
          }

        parent::validateOrder(
            $id_cart,
            $id_order_state,
            $amount_paid,
            $payment_method,
            $message,
            $extra_vars,
            $currency_special,
            $dont_touch_amount,
            $secure_key,
            $shop
        );

    }
```

Underneath you will find the last part the original Method:

```
                    $data = array(
                    '{firstname}' => $this->context->customer->firstname,
                    '{lastname}' => $this->context->customer->lastname,
                    '{email}' => $this->context->customer->email,
                    '{delivery_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, "\n"),
                    '{invoice_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, "\n"),
                    '{delivery_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, '<br />', array(
                        'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
                        'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
                    )),
                    '{invoice_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, '<br />', array(
                            'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
                            'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
                    )),
                    '{delivery_company}' => $delivery->company,
                    '{delivery_firstname}' => $delivery->firstname,
                    '{delivery_lastname}' => $delivery->lastname,
                    '{delivery_address1}' => $delivery->address1,
                    '{delivery_address2}' => $delivery->address2,
                    '{delivery_city}' => $delivery->city,
                    '{delivery_postal_code}' => $delivery->postcode,
                    '{delivery_country}' => $delivery->country,
                    '{delivery_state}' => $delivery->id_state ? $delivery_state->name : '',
                    '{delivery_phone}' => ($delivery->phone) ? $delivery->phone : $delivery->phone_mobile,
                    '{delivery_other}' => $delivery->other,
                    '{invoice_company}' => $invoice->company,
                    '{invoice_vat_number}' => $invoice->vat_number,
                    '{invoice_firstname}' => $invoice->firstname,
                    '{invoice_lastname}' => $invoice->lastname,
                    '{invoice_address2}' => $invoice->address2,
                    '{invoice_address1}' => $invoice->address1,
                    '{invoice_city}' => $invoice->city,
                    '{invoice_postal_code}' => $invoice->postcode,
                    '{invoice_country}' => $invoice->country,
                    '{invoice_state}' => $invoice->id_state ? $invoice_state->name : '',
                    '{invoice_phone}' => ($invoice->phone) ? $invoice->phone : $invoice->phone_mobile,
                    '{invoice_other}' => $invoice->other,
                    '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
                    '{date}' => Tools::displayDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), null, 1),
                    '{carrier}' => ($virtual_product || !isset($carrier->name)) ? Tools::displayError('No carrier') : $carrier->name,
                    '{payment}' => Tools::substr($order->payment, 0, 32),
                    '{products}' => $product_list_html,
                    '{products_txt}' => $product_list_txt,
                    '{discounts}' => $cart_rules_list_html,
                    '{discounts_txt}' => $cart_rules_list_txt,
                    '{total_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_paid, $this->context->currency, false),
                    '{total_products}' => Tools::displayPrice(Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? $order->total_products : $order->total_products_wt, $this->context->currency, false),
                    '{total_discounts}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_discounts, $this->context->currency, false),
                    '{total_shipping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_shipping, $this->context->currency, false),
                    '{total_wrapping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_wrapping, $this->context->currency, false),
                    '{total_tax_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice(($order->total_products_wt - $order->total_products) + ($order->total_shipping_tax_incl - $order->total_shipping_tax_excl), $this->context->currency, false));

                    if (is_array($extra_vars)) {
                        $data = array_merge($data, $extra_vars);
                    }

                    // Join PDF invoice
                    if ((int)Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE') && $order_status->invoice && $order->invoice_number) {
                        $order_invoice_list = $order->getInvoicesCollection();
                        Hook::exec('actionPDFInvoiceRender', array('order_invoice_list' => $order_invoice_list));
                        $pdf = new PDF($order_invoice_list, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE, $this->context->smarty);
                        $file_attachement['content'] = $pdf->render(false);
                        $file_attachement['name'] = Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE_PREFIX', (int)$order->id_lang, null, $order->id_shop).sprintf('%06d', $order->invoice_number).'.pdf';
                        $file_attachement['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
                    } else {
                        $file_attachement = null;
                    }

                    if (self::DEBUG_MODE) {
                        PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - Mail is about to be sent', 1, null, 'Cart', (int)$id_cart, true);
                    }

                    if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email)) {
                        Mail::Send(
                            (int)$order->id_lang,
                            'order_conf',
                            Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
                            $data,
                            $this->context->customer->email,
                            $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
                            null,
                            null,
                            $file_attachement,
                            null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
                        );
                    }
                }

                // updates stock in shops
                if (Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
                    $product_list = $order->getProducts();
                    foreach ($product_list as $product) {
                        // if the available quantities depends on the physical stock
                        if (StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['product_id'])) {
                            // synchronizes
                            StockAvailable::synchronize($product['product_id'], $order->id_shop);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $order->updateOrderDetailTax();
            } else {
                $error = Tools::displayError('Order creation failed');
                PrestaShopLogger::addLog($error, 4, '0000002', 'Cart', intval($order->id_cart));
                die($error);
            }
        } // End foreach $order_detail_list

        // Use the last order as currentOrder
        if (isset($order) && $order->id) {
            $this->currentOrder = (int)$order->id;
        }

        if (self::DEBUG_MODE) {
            PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - End of validateOrder', 1, null, 'Cart', (int)$id_cart, true);
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        $error = Tools::displayError('Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart');
        PrestaShopLogger::addLog($error, 4, '0000001', 'Cart', intval($this->context->cart->id));
        die($error);
    }
}
```

You will find the if statement I'm trying to skip almost at the bottom of the method.

As you can see, one of the arguments, $extra_vars = array(), gets merged with the $data array inside the function. Is there a way to skip the if statement this way? Because i have no ideas left on how to solve this problem.

Comment: When extending the class, you could override the method, and call the parent method with the same args, but `$extra_vars = null`. This would fail the `if` condition, skipping the `array_merge`.

Comment: The hacky solution would be to set a dummy invalid email address to `$this->context->customer->email` when redefine the method.

Comment: @Yoshi Thank you for helping out. I already extended the original abstract Class, and changed my code, but i'ts still sending an e-mail. even when i change it to null when calling the Method. could you please show me in an awser so i know what to do?

Comment: I see, we're not talking about the extra_vars. You actually want to skip sending emails, then just refer to Taufik's comment. I don't see another way, as skipping *chunks of code* is not really possible.

Comment: @TaufikNurrohman thank you for helping me! I already tried this a few days ago when calling the function like this (the extra_vars array): arrray('{email}' => 'me@igotnomailadressnomore.com'), but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: @Yoshi I was also trying to find a way to place /* before the if statement and */ after the last } of the if statement, but i really have no idea how i could do this

Comment: The condition `if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email)) {` issn't using `$extra_vars` or `$data`, it's directly accessing `$this->context->customer->email`, so this is the value you need to fiddle with.

Comment: @Yoshi Thank's again, but as described, i already did try this by using arrray('{email}' => 'me@igotnomailadressnomore.com'), in the extra_vars argument when calling it, but it didn't seem to replace the original {email} even though i know it should.

Comment: Again, the condition<<< issn't using any of the data arrays. It's directly using some other value stored in `$this->context->customer->email`. So it's completely irrelevant what you put in `$data` or `$extra_vars`, because those fields will not be used for evaluation.

Comment: @Yoshi I have been at this for days and extremely tired.... i TOTALLY missed this... thank you so much for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `$this->context->customer->email` is writable, you could do something like:

```
<?php

//...

$customerEmail = $this->context->customer->email;
$this->context->customer->email = null;

parent::validateOrder(
    $id_cart,
    $id_order_state,
    $amount_paid,
    $payment_method,
    $message,
    $extra_vars,
    $currency_special,
    $dont_touch_amount,
    $secure_key,
    $shop
);

$this->context->customer->email = $customerEmail;
```

I wouldn't advice this, but if you're desperate it would probably work.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help. No luck so far though.

Comment: Well, there might be a way to affect `Mail::Send`, have you checked whether that class exposes some api to temporarily disable message sending?

Comment: This is a great suggestion! I will find out and i will comment again as soon as possible!

Comment: Wait, this is OOP, so in order to change the e-mail address (as you described in your awnser), a new instance of the Class which is responsible for setting $this->context->customer->email should be created in order to temporarily set it to null, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, you would still need to overwatch the creation and usage of that new class. All in order to simply disable some email-sending at a totally unrelated code point. This feels all very dirty, so I'd personally would try to evaluate all other options first. Mainly configuration and similar.

Comment: You are absolutely right about this not being the best way in order to prevent a simple mail being sent... i will try other options first. if i have no other way, the in have to do it this way. If i do have to use it, i will mark your awnser as correct, because it is correct after all. Maybe a bit too much, but again: Thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: Hi Yoshi, you are right concerning every aspect. It's dirty. Do you know the song "it's beginning to look a lot like Christmas"? In the end, i was pretty much singing "it's beginning to look a lot like hacking". This CMS system properly checks the (email) field(s), so those "errors" had to be bypassed as well. I gave up and chose a different path to achieve what i wanted. I will mark your awnser as correct though, because in the end, to achieve what i wanted, your awnser is correct. You're a great coder.